# Unable to log back in after logging out

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-identity-2

Using Visual Studio 2019, asp.net core 2.2, and razor pages, I have used Visual Studio's feature to add "new scaffolded item" and then selected "Identity" and then I selected the Account Login, Account Logout, Forgot Password, Access Denied, Register, Reset Password options. I added a new Layout page to use with these scaffolded pages so I can control the styles and layout of it. Logging in, registering, and changing password all works. The problem is, once a user logs out, they cannot log back in again and the only way to get logged in is to reset the password. This is pretty strange because on the back end in the razor page actions, I haven't modified any of the scaffolded code.

I've tried typing the browser route /Account/Logout to insure that it is logging out properly. I have used the debugger on the Login action and I can see that the account is not locked out. I don't have two factor enabled so that should not be the problem. The sign in manager fails to log in even though I am 100% certain that the password is correct.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _sendGridApiKey = Configuration["AuthMessageSenderOptions:SendGridKey"];

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<MyAppUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");

        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    }
```

[image]

There is no error message given by the sign in manager, but I can see with the debugger that the sign in manager fails to authenticate the user. If I reset the password, the sign in manager will succeed. Then, after I explicitly log out, that same password no longer works and I must reset again to successfully authenticate once again.

Answer (score 1):

Make the breakpoint at the line of signInManager , and find that the result is `NotAllowed` ."Not Allowed" makes sense, but there was no error message that came back with it - so it wasn't the best way to know what's going on. Luckily .NET Core is easy to dive into the source code with.

NotAllowed is only set here:

```
protected virtual async Task<SignInResult> PreSignInCheck(TUser user)
    {
        if (!await CanSignInAsync(user))
        {
            return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
        }
        if (await IsLockedOut(user))
        {
            return await LockedOut(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

CanSignInAsync method

```
public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
    {
        if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(0, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed email.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
            return false;
        }
        if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(1, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then the cause of the problem is in your Startup.cs Configuration

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
   ...
   options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
   ...
}
```

You could refer to the following method to resolve

1.pop into the database and set your user as `EmailConfirmed = true`

2.set the `EmailConfirmed` as true in the Register method like below :

```
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
user.EmailConfirmed = true;
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Comment: @tnk479 , Do you mean that you  still login failed when the EmailConfirmed file in the AspNetUsers table is true ?[Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EXKHqgMy8t9Hl5ptgah0GTwB-2CI6IegasEQovyUCHXAjg?e=WIP0HV) is my working project , you could refer to . If you still have the issue , could you share more details or a demo that can reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Yes, the EmailConfirmed field in the AspNetUsers table is true. I think I may have figured out the problem. I override OnModelCreating method in the DbContext and in that override, I am using the HasData function on my apps User class (which inherits from IdentityUser). I am setting the password there. So each time I deploy, that is getting called and its resetting the password back to the password I specified in the HasData.

Comment: What is the proper thing for me to do with a question like this where you provided a reasonably good answer that could help some people, but it wasn't exactly the resolution to the problem I encountered?